# How to use ROS to interact with the simulation software on windows

Tags: linux, windows, ros

I want to use ROS as a multi-agent environment for my simulation software on Windows. May I ask, is it possible? Because ROS is built on Linux and my simulation software is on windows.

Comment: ROS1 does not have a windows build. ROS2 is the only one supported on Windows

Comment: Thanks, so ROS2 is possible for this. Do you have any suggestions on tutorials for me to read？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in our comments you will have to use ROS2 for Windows support. You can find install steps [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation.html) and you can find tutorial [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials.html)